# Object and variable are null in dialog after recreating the activity

Tags: android, dialog, android-camera, activity-lifecycle

In my activity when I click on a menu item in the actionbar a dialog comes up. This dialog has an ImageView. When I click on the ImageView I can open the camera. When I shoot a picture my app force closes, and I think it's because I can't refer to the imageView in the dialog after the recreation of the activity because it does not exist or is not initialized.

**onActivityResult**

```
case PICK_FROM_CAMERA_EDIT:             
if (data != null) {
     Uri imageuri = data.getData();
    Log.i("CAMERA_URI", String.valueOf(imageuri)); //content://media/external/images/media/72954
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        //creating bitmap from uri
        edit_dialog.iv_bucket2.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //force close

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

See? This is the problem:

```
edit_dialog.iv_bucket2.setImageBitmap(scaled);
```

`edit_dialog` is not null BUT `edit_dialog.iv_bucket2` is null.

This is defined in `onCreate()` as

```
edit_dialog = new EditBucketDialog(MyActivity.this);
```

and opened on clicking the menu item as

```
edit_dialog = new EditBucketDialog(MyActivity.this);
edit_dialog.setCancelable(true);
edit_dialog.show();
```

This is the class in a nutshell:

```
public class EditBucketDialog extends Dialog {

    //variables
    ImageView iv_bucket2;

     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.edit_dialog);
            iv_bucket2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_bucket2);
    }
}
```

**This is also true for other variables in the dialog I want to refer to from onActivityResult**.

I also have

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Strange thing is that this happens only once. I need to uninstall and install the app to bring up this issue again.

Comment: Where you casting edit_dialog.iv_bucket2? ?

Comment: What? I don't understand

Comment: something like edit_dialog.iv_bucket2=(Bitmap)edit_dialog.findViewById(myid);

Comment: Obviously, in Dialog class. I added the line

Comment: Okay,i am asking because i thought you need to reinitialize widgets, I am little confused you calling camera as well showing dialog on same button click? If m right then you need to initialize dialog class after camera click before setting the image.